# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function, if-statement, apply

I am trying to apply one funtion to a column but i am getting the error

```
Name    weight
Person1 30
Person2 70
```

My code is below

```
def classify(x):
    if 0 <= x < 20:
        y = "0 to 20%"
    if 20 < x < 40:
        y = "20 to 40%"
    if 40 < x < 60:
        y = "40 to 60%"
    if 60 < x < 80:
        y = "60 to 80%"
    if 80 < x <= 100:
        y = "80 to 100%"
    return ( y)
```

`df['Target'] = df['weight'].apply(lambda x: classify(x))` throwing the Local bound error

If I use print instead of return I am able to see the outputs

Expected out

```
    Name    weight  Target
    Person1     30  20 to 40
    Person2     70  60 to 80
```

Comment: You need an `else` clause so that `y` is defined when none of your conditions are met. But `cut` is the way to do this

Comment: I put else: False, Then my Target is 'False' for 2 rows

Comment: And what is the value of `weight` for those two rows... Should be pretty simple to see why it's breaking. (My guess is 20, 40, 60 or 80). You seem to be missing some `<=` signs

Comment: You try to execute with csv file with 2 lines only. Jusee the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using `cut`

```
df['Target']=pd.cut(df['weight'],[0,20,40,60,80,100])
```